# How to join two or more CSV files in Apache Nifi or How to copy columns to a CSV file from another

Tags: csv, merge, apache-nifi

Assuming I have two CSV files that have no common column but have the same number of rows. How can we just do a merge of these files in Nifi?

Ex: File 1

```
ColA ColB
A1   B1
A2   B2
```

File 2

```
ColC ColD
C1   D1
C2   D2
```

Output should be

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD
A1   B1   C1   D1 
A2   B2   C2   D2
```

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for "joining" two sets of records is with LookupRecord, there is a CSVLookupRecord service but the lookup pattern requires keys/columns to match.

For your use case you can still use LookupRecord but instead of using a built-in CSV lookup service, you'd want a ScriptedLookupService. You can use a scripting language like Groovy to write a custom lookup service that reads in File 2, and instead of trying to match a common key/field/column, you'd just return the current line in the lookup file and advance to the next line.